# Slide Effect In Javascript Without Jquery

Tags: effects

I'm working on my own libarary, and I thought that a slide effect function would be useful, plus, I'm making a Calender/Clock web-app and its goal is to be as effect-filled as possible. I have no doe so far. Sorry. I searched all over the web.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make text slide in or out, CSS would be the most efficient. You could use the Javascript setTimeout method in a for-loop, but a CSS animation would look the smoothest.
I made a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ERR2g/44/).

Here's the CSS behind it.

```
div.slide {
    transition: left, 2s;
    -moz-transition: left, 2s;
    -webkit-transition: left, 2s;
    -ms-transition: left, 2s;
    position:relative;
    left:-150px;
    border: solid black 2px;
    width:50px;
}
div.hov {
    border:solid black 2px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
}
div.hov:hover div.slide {
    left:48px;
}
```

Highlight over the 'calendar' to see the effects.